# Why does remote desktop connection flash from one PC but not others?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, remote-desktop, windows-terminal-services

I have 20 PCs (Windows XP) in remote locations connecting to the same server (Windows Server 2003) using Remote Desktop over a VPN.  On just one of the PCs the remote desktop screen flashes (redraws) multiple times after connecting, the others don't.  The screen resolution is the same: local is 800x600 32bit; RDP file is set to full screen, 256 color; remote when connected is 800x600 8bit color.

Any suggestions what the problem might be, or what to investigate next?

Comment: Are there any TS policy differences for the machine which flickers?

Answer (score 1):

Several things come to mind:
1. Bad video driver
2. Video card hardware issues
3. Network card issues (driver / configuration / or hardware)
4. Machine overloaded, including high ram utilization, slow hd, etc.

Questions for you to ask yourself
Is this machine pretty much identical to the others hardware wise?
What is different about the software configuration; including service packs, drivers, and hot fixes?

If they are identical hardware / software wise, then I'd guess it's a hardware failure.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth checking the version of the Remote Desktop client. It's possible the problem machine is using one of the older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Network connection at the remote site?

Also, try clearing the local RDP bitmap cache and see if it helps.